# How to select Hidden Field?

Tags: jquery

I want to select field with following condition

1. Id start with **Product**

   OR
2. Id start with **Product** and **Hidden** field

My following code will only satisfy first condition **I also want to satisfy 2nd condition**. How is possible?

```
$("input[id^=Product]").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[id^=Product]:hidden')
```

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

If you really want an `OR` in the means target both with idStartsWith and idStartsWith+it'sHidden do like:

```
$('input[id^=Product], input[id^=Product]:hidden')
```

Comment: Work like charm! Thank you so much

Comment: I want `idStartsWith OR idStartsWith+it'sHidden` your first line code working fine and second one not working

Comment: @Sadikhasan It's working as you can see here: http://jsbin.com/soruvi/1/edit?html,js,console,output Or depends in what means you think about an `OR` statement :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You can use [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) for input hidden type, put `[type='hidden']` in selector

```
$("input[type='hidden'][id^=Product]").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**EDIT** - As OP want to satisfy both condition. You can use comma separated selectors for this. Put your earlier selector with comma separated above selector. See code below -

```
$("input[id^=Product],input[type='hidden'][id^=Product]").each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
   });
```

Comment: I want to search product start ID with either `product` or start with product and `hidden` both condition I want to find.